# Using variable as fixed input value for Buffer in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, buffer

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I want to show/create a buffer of a single point but the radius of that buffer depends on a simple formula (e.g. Radius = a*b*c).

Instead of entering directly the radius, is there are way to just enter the constants on the ModelBuilder, use the result and connect it to the Buffer tool so that we can get that result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward, but you may do well to read the [Creating Tools With ModelBuilder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007v000000) help:

You might also check the help on the [Calculate Value](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000004000000.htm) tool in ModelBuilder:

[image]

1. Open ModelBuilder and add your feature class/shapefile and your buffer tool.
2. Add the "Calculate Value" ModelBuilder function (Accessed by right clicking the model area and selecting  Model Only Tools>Calculate Values).
3. Add 3 (or however many you please) variables to your model (Insert>Create Variable) of a data type appropriate for your operation. Name these something easy and appropriate (e.g. A,B,C).
4. Right-click these variables and enable "Model Parameter".
5. Open the Calculate Value tool and set its expression to whatever you'd like using the variables encased in % %, as such: %A% * %B% * %C% (this will be the product of A*B*C).

[image]

6. Connect the Calculate Value tool to the Buffer tool as the Distance unit.